# use p6 web service in .net

Tags: wcf, web-services, interop, weblogic, primavera

There are a lot of web services installed on Primavera P6.
WSDL: ActivityCodeAssignment.wsdl

Primary Key Field: A multi-part key comprised of the following elements:

```
ActivityObjectId
ActivityCodeTypeObjectId
```

Target Namespace: http://xmlns.oracle.com/Primavera/P6/WS/ActivityCodeAssignment/V1

Default Transport URLs:

```
http://<hostname>:<port number>/p6ws/services/ActivityCodeAssignment?wsdl
https://<hostname>:<port number>/p6ws/services/ActivityCodeAssignment?wsdl
```

But if I input this on the web brower:
    http://my-machine:7005/p6ws/services/ActivityCodeAssignment?wsdl

It shows, "No service was found."

If I try to Add Service Reference in Visual Studio, it says.

```
There was an error downloading 'http://my-machine:7005/p6ws/services/ActivityCodeAssignment?wsdl'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://my-machine:7005/p6ws/services/ActivityCodeAssignment?wsdl'.
There was no endpoint listening at http://my-machine:7005/p6ws/services/ActivityCodeAssignment?wsdl that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

Is P6 using some different web service?

Answer (score 3):

On my machine, running Oracle database, Weblogic server with P6 version 8.1 Web Services, the URL for this is:

```
http://<hostname>:<port number>/p6ws/services/ActivityCodeAssignmentService?wsdl
```

Note the word "Service" tacked onto the end.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of P6 you are using.

Firstly, please check the root web service URL is working or not:

[http://hostname:port/p6ws]

If not, you may need to check your P6 Web Services is installed and deployed correctly or not.

This is P6 Web Services Administrator’s Guide for version 7.0:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16281_01/Technical_Documentation/Web_Services/wsadmin.pdf

If you can access the root web services and other endpoint such as ActivityService [http://host:port/p6ws/services/ActivityService?wsdl] rather than ActivityCodeAssignmentService, but you want to use it, you may need to build your own WS Stubs with following steps:

> 1. Create a Class Library project in .NET with the name P6WSStubs
> 2. Change the Root Namespace to Primavera
> 3. Add a reference to Microsoft WSE 3.0.
> 4. Add the following Web Reference Ws.P6.ActivityCodeAssignment - [http://hostname:port/p6ws/services/ActivityCodeAssignmentService?wsdl]
> 5. Build the P6WSStubs.dll

Hope it will help you,

Yogi